# Is there anyway to use Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP) devices on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, osx-mavericks

I am working a project that transmits data over Bluetooth SPP and would like to use Mac OS X "Mavericks" as an interface. I have read that certain options in the Bluetooth Menu in System Preferences have been removed which may prohibit this from being possible.

Is there anyway ("maybe virtual machine of a Linux variant") that will allow this to work?

Comment: Resolved issue.

Paired device with Bluetooth menu.

Checked /dev/ for specific tty listing.

"screen" connection ensures that the device stays connected.

Comment: Post that as an answer, please, and then accept it after two days. We want other users to find their answers easily. Why? Because the purpose of [su] (and sites in the [se] network in general) is not to solve your specific problem; it's to provide knowledge to the worldwide audience of the Internet.

Comment: @AlejandroEscobar I don't think you're around here anymore, but if you can further explain how you got this working, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 2):

See related post on Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169437/bluetooth-spp-support-in-os-x-yosemite

I was able to pair a bluetooth serial port via the preferences panel (using the paring wizard from the menu extra should also work):

```
Apple Menu > System Preferences... > Bluetooth
```

My adapter was discoverable, failed auto-pairing, but I was able to pair with the pin code provided in the online documentation. The system automatically created a serial port:

```
alf@my-mac:~ ls -l /dev/tty.*
...
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   6 Aug 12 15:09 /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Screen will open this port, but I don't have the correct baud rate just yet:

```
screen /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB 9600
```